# How to display number of rows and columns of a csv file in a django web app

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to get a csv file from the user and then simply want to display the number of rows and columns in that file to the user

testapp.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="rowcol">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">

<button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def testapp(request):
    return render(request, 'testapp.html', {})

def rowcol(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.POST["file"]
        dataset=pd.read_csv('file')
        count_row = dataset.shape[0]
        count_col = dataset.shape[1]
        ans=("<H1>%d,%d</H1>",count_row,count_col)
        return HttpResponse(ans)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from testapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.testapp, name='testapp'),
    path('', views.rowcol, name='rowcol'),
]
```

urls.py in outer folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('testapp.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, what's wrong with the current code? are you get any error or what? you should explain your problem in detail so that others can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems here. First of all, your `path(..)`s clash with each other. You need to provide a different path for the second path. For example:

```
# testapp/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from testapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.testapp, name='testapp'),
    path('rowcol/', views.rowcol, name='rowcol'),
]
```

Next in your template, you better use an `{% url ... %}` template tag, and set `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'rowcol' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv">
    <button type="submit">Upload text</button>
</form>
```

Finally in your view function, you forgot to format the string:

```
def rowcol(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['file']
        dataset=pd.read_csv(file)
        count_row, count_col = dataset.shape
        ans='<H1>%d,%d</H1>' % (count_row,count_col)
        return HttpResponse(ans)
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: @Sunvir: did you upload a (.csv) file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am still getting the following error:                                              MultiValueDictKeyError at /rowcol/
'file'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/rowcol/
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 
'file'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Sunvir\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80

Comment: Yes it was a .csv file

Comment: @Sunvir: ah, you wrote `request.POST`, but it is `request.FILES`.